# Explode function to extract values from DMS notation

Tags: php, google-maps, gps, substring, explode

I have a table with locations stored in the format:

```
30°28'25"  
68°28'43"
```

In the process of converting from DMS to DEC, I'd need a function to convert the string 68°28'43" (no spaces among values-symbols) into

```
$deg = 68  
$min = 28  
$sec = 43
```

Or something similar. Thanks

Comment: *I'd need a function to convert the string* so how far have you got in writing one?

Comment: @NigelRen RiggsFolly I get it, but as there were more symbos I wanted to avoid repeating str_replace several times

Comment: The point is you didnt even show us that you had made any effort at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use **[preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/de/function.preg-match-all.php)** :)

the following regex simply captures every digits (\d) which are contains exactly 2 numbers ({2}) and group them (the braces around the expression)

```
<?php
$value = "68°28'43\"";
preg_match_all('/(\d{2})/', $value, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

$matches would be an array with the captured results (the digits)

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 68
            [1] => 28
            [2] => 43
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 68
            [1] => 28
            [2] => 43
        )

)
```

And then you can simply assign it to your variables with the list() function as follow:

```
list($deg, $min, $sec) = $matches[0];

echo $deg; // 68
echo $min; // 28
echo $sec; // 43
```

Comment: I think the function fails when value has . or - symbols which shouldn't be ripped off the string

Comment: what exactly do you mean?

Comment: try the function with values like -68°28.453'43.213"